# Sort in mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2

Tags: node.js, sorting, mongoose, aggregate, pagination

I am using mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2

and sort does not work

```
var aggregate = searchmodel.aggregate()
aggregate.match({ word: { $regex: `.*${word}.*` } })
  .group({
    _id: '$user_id', doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' }
  })
var options = {
  page: page, limit: 50, sort: { createdAt: -1 }
}
searchmodel.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, options).then(function (results) {
  return res.json(results)
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

I tried lot of things for sort but it does not work at all

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the solution to the problem.
You need to add _id to the sort object.

Example:

```
  const options = {
    page: page,
    limit: limit,
    sort: { _id: 1, createdAt: -1 },
  };
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should write,

```
var aggregate = searchmodel.aggregate()
aggregate.match({ word: { $regex: `.*${word}.*` } })
  .group({
    _id: '$user_id', doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' }
  })
var options = {
  page: page, limit: 50, sort: { createdAt: 'desc' }
}
searchmodel.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, options).then(function (results) {
  return res.json(results)
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```